# How to implement ILastUpdateInfoFactory Ocean 2013?

Tags: c#, ocean, petrel

I'm a newbie on Ocean Schlumberger 2013. I've been trying to use the **LastModified** Property from Slb.Ocean.Petrel.XXX (Where XXX means *Well, VolumeCalculation, etc*) but when I use it I get the following warning.

> Warning   1   'Slb.Ocean.Petrel.DomainObject.Model.LastModified' is
>   obsolete: '"Obsolete in 2013.1. Please use ILastUpdateInfoFactory
>   instead."'    C:\Users\XXXX\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\ListGr\ListGr\ListGrLogs.cs 113 25 ListGr

I already read the **ILastUpdateInfoFactory** help documentation but I dunno how to implement this on my plugin and obtain a similar result to *LastModified* property. Can someone give me a hand with this?

Regards.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Don't you know how to implement an interface? Or is it implementation specific? Please explain more.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is what you are looking for, but from the Ocean help file on ILastUpdateInfoFactory:

```
// Code that gets the LastUpdateInfo from an native or custom domain object
public void GetLastUpdateInfo(object domainObject)
{
    // Get the service
    ILastUpdateInfoFactory lastUpdateInfoFactory = CoreSystem.GetService<ILastUpdateInfoFactory>(domainObject);

    // Get the LastUpdateInfo
    LastUpdateInfo lastUpdateInfo = lastUpdateInfoFactory.GetLastUpdateInfo(domainObject);

    // Process the result
    PetrelLogger.InfoOutputWindow(string.Format("Last updated at: {0} by {1}.",
                                            lastUpdateInfo.Time, lastUpdateInfo.UserName));
}
```